# how can i extract this part of my JSON response

Tags: php, json

i can extract user id from JSON response,i get response from telegram bot API, but i can not extract file_id.
here is my code:

```
 <?php
$response='{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":514191839,"message":{"message_id":898,"from":{"id":100000000,"first_name":"Nnn","username":"myid"},"chat":{"id":101150186,"first_name":"Nnn","username":"myid","type":"private"},"date":1487570256,"photo":[{"file_id":"AgADBAAD4KcxG9qfWFEqGZHRzv1IReOGnhkABOym5qINB41gwLIBAAEC","file_size":480,"width":90,"height":44},{"file_id":"AgADBAAD4KcxG9qfWFEqGZHRzv1IReOGnhkABCkXQqPZCWHswbIBAAEC","file_size":2694,"width":273,"height":132}]}}]}';
$arrayUpdate= json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($arrayUpdate['result'] as $key) {

                echo "user id is:".$key['message']['from']['id']."<br />";
                echo "photo file id is:".$key['photo']['file_id'];

}
?>
```

Comment: what is the print_r($key); ?

Comment: @naga sorry i don't get your mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `photo` is an array of elements. So, for example, if you want to extract the first one, you should use:

```
echo "photo file id is:".$key['message']['photo'][0]['file_id'];
```

Comment: photo is an sub array of message so it won't work @Matteo Piano

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arrayUpdate['result'] as $key) {

    echo "user id is:" . $key['message']['from']['id'] . "<br />";
    foreach ($key['message']['photo'] as $photo) {
        echo "photo file id is:" . $photo['file_id'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: this works too,thanks,(but returns photo id 2 times)

Comment: because you have two file_id in photo check it before foreach `print_r($arrayUpdate);`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
   $response='{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":514191839,"message":{"message_id":898,"from":{"id":100000000,"first_name":"Nnn","username":"myid"},"chat":{"id":101150186,"first_name":"Nnn","username":"myid","type":"private"},"date":1487570256,"photo":[{"file_id":"AgADBAAD4KcxG9qfWFEqGZHRzv1IReOGnhkABOym5qINB41gwLIBAAEC","file_size":480,"width":90,"height":44},{"file_id":"AgADBAAD4KcxG9qfWFEqGZHRzv1IReOGnhkABCkXQqPZCWHswbIBAAEC","file_size":2694,"width":273,"height":132}]}}]}';
$arrayUpdate= json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($arrayUpdate['result'] as $key) {

                echo "user id is:".$key['message']['from']['id']."<br />";
                foreach ($key['message']['photo'] as $photo) {
                echo "photo file id is:".$photo['file_id'];
                }

}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree but there he hardcoded the index with `[0]`. In my code it is dynamic. So, if the objects in the array will be more it will automatically handle all the `file_id`.